# xarray RMSE of each XY cell from the median

Tags: python, python-xarray

I've written a leave one out spatial interpolation routine using xarray where an interpolation is done n-1 times across the input data. Each iteration of the interpolation is stored in an xarray dataset under a "IterN" dimension. Here's an example:

```
grids
Out[2]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:   (IterN: 84, northing: 53, easting: 54)
Coordinates:
  * easting   (easting) float64 5.648e+05 5.653e+05 ... 5.907e+05 5.912e+05
  * northing  (northing) float64 4.333e+06 4.334e+06 ... 4.359e+06 4.359e+06
  * IterN     (IterN) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83
Data variables:
    Data      (IterN, northing, easting) float64 2.065 2.018 ... 0.3037 0.2913
```

I can compute some statistics over the dataset using the in-built functions, for example median here:

```
median = grids.median(dim="IterN")
median
Out[5]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:   (northing: 53, easting: 54)
Coordinates:
  * easting   (easting) float64 5.648e+05 5.653e+05 ... 5.907e+05 5.912e+05
  * northing  (northing) float64 4.333e+06 4.334e+06 ... 4.359e+06 4.359e+06
Data variables:
    Data      (northing, easting) float64 2.111 2.061 2.011 ... 0.3104 0.2992
```

I would like to compute the root mean square error of the iteration sets against something like the median above. I can't see an inbuilt function for this, and I'm struggling to see how to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60797418/calculate-root-squared-error-of-xarray-dataset).

The desired output is an RMSE grid in the same XY dimensions as the other grids.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Does the following go in the direction you mean?

```
median = grids.median(dim="IterN")
error = grids - median
rmse = np.sqrt((error**2).mean("IterN"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).